# How to undo Qt.FramelessWindowHint from a QMainWindow?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qmainwindow, frameless

The application that I am trying to make needs a frameless window in the first stage, then I need to set it framed back.

so I need to inactivate the following line -->
`self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

I searched a lot but I had no satisfying answer.
Can you please help me, guys?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint, False)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are almost there, inside your mainwindow init,
First you have to add this line while initialization,

```py
Flags = QtCore.Qt.QWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTop)
self.setWindowFlags(Flags)
```

Later you can set None to windowflags. Hope this helps.

Comment: If this is your answer then upvote and accept my answer.